# How to tell what type of filesystem you're on?

Tags: command-line, filesystems

Is there a command to tell what type of filesystem you're using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43237/863 (Yes it's newer, but it has a) an accepted answer and b) also works for unmounted filesystems _and_ image files)

Comment: It would help for the target operating system(s) to be specified. Most of the answers assume it is Linux but this isn't stated in the question.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/309047/how-do-i-find-out-what-filesystem-my-partitions-are-using

Comment: Related Q&A I just added: [How do I find out which partitions my filesystems (and mount points) are on, and how full they are?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/733886/114401)

Answer (score 29):

Your question can be taken several ways. Literally Karlson's answer is pretty cool because it tells you the filesystem of the volume | partition that you are currently on.

`df -hT` I have always liked this command because it shows you all the "standard" filesystems that are mounted and does it in human-readable size format.

However, you may have other disks or volumes that are not mounted (commented out), failed to mount, or have been unmounted. Another thing you can do is to run `cat /etc/fstab` this will show you the "filesystem table" and list the filesystems that are supposed to be mounted on boot along with the location, filesystem type, mountpoint, and more.

Comment: I just want to note that if you see `fuseblk`, it's (most likely) NTFS.

Comment: @phunehehe No, it can be exFAT as well.

Answer (score 24):

The `stat` command on Linux systems is used to display file or file system status. For more information read manpage by running `man stat` in terminal.

```
$ stat -f -c %T /
xfs
$ stat -f -c %T /boot
ext2/ext3
$ stat -f -c %T /srv
btrfs
$ stat -f -c %T /tmp
tmpfs
```

Flags used above:

`-f, --file-system` - display file system status instead of file status

`-c  --format=FORMAT` - use the specified FORMAT instead of the default output a newline after each use of FORMAT

Valid format sequences for file systems:

`%T` - Type in human readable form

Comment: If it matters, I believe this is specific to Linux.

Comment: It never shows `ext4`!

Comment: @ChrisDown is right, at least on MacOS the `stat` command lacks the `--file-system` option (`-f` is stilla  valid option, but have a different meaning).

Comment: For anyone else who misinterpreted the manual pages, `man stat` lists `%T` among others, twice. The "valid format sequences for file systems" section of relevant when using the `-f` option.

Comment: On an Azure Ubuntu VM, I get `tmpfs` for every block device, and `ext2/ext3` for directories. This contradicts the output from `df -T`, `lsblk -f`, `blkid`, etc.

Answer (score 10):

If you do:

```
df -k .
```

It will tell you what filesystem your current directory is on.

Comment: `df .` is enough for this. And, if you need to know the filesystem *type*, `df -T .` will do.

Comment: To see the partition of some specific file check [here](http://www.linuxstall.com/find-partition-hard-disk-belonging-specific-file/).

Comment: Only `df -T` or `df --print-type` works on the latest Mint.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `lsblk -f` and `blkid` to get information about your filesystems and their properties.

Answer (score 4):

```
df -T . | awk '{ getline ; print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `df .`, which will tell you on what filesystem the current directory resides.  Then run `mount`, which will produce a list of mounted filesystems along with their types and mount options.  This works for me:

```
mount | fgrep -w "`df . | grep '%' | sed -e 's/.*% *//'`"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`blkid -o value -s TYPE "$DEV"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53371/863), it also works for unmounted devices or even image files.

Answer (score 2):

On GNU Linux you can get an overview of your storage using `lsblk` and then get the file system type for the device you're interested using something like one of the following:

- `$ fsck -N /dev/sda1` (you don't need superuser powers to use this command)
- `$ df -T /dev/sda1` (doesn't require superuser powers, but requires the file system to be mounted)
- `# file -s /dev/sda1`
- `# blkid /dev/sda1`

These may be useful if your file system is on a LVM volume, since `lsblk` won't tell you what file system is in there.

Answer (score 0):

`cat /etc/mtab` for mounted filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

For an overview of all filesystems:

```
lsblk -f
```

To get just the name, type, filesystem, and partition type:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,TYPE,FSTYPE,PTTYPE
NAME    TYPE FSTYPE   PTTYPE
sda     disk          gpt
├─sda1  part ext4     gpt
├─sda14 part          gpt
└─sda15 part vfat     gpt
sdb     disk          dos
└─sdb1  part ext4     dos
sdd     disk
```

To get just the filesystem for a specific partition (`-n` removes the header):

```
$ lsblk -n -o FSTYPE /dev/sda1
ext4
```