# Find filesystem of an unmounted partition from a script

Tags: command-line, filesystems, system-installation, block-device

I'm writing a custom automated install using AIF (Arch Installation Framework), and I need to find the filesystem on a partition given a partition.

So far I have this:

```
grok_partitions () {
    local partitions=
    for label in `ls /dev/disk/by-label | grep "Arch"`
    do
        if [ $label == "Arch" ]
        then
            mount_point="/"
        else
            IFS="-" read base mount <<< "${label}"
            mount_point="/${mount}"
        fi

        local partition=$(readlink -f /dev/disk/by-label/${label})
        local part_no=$(echo ${partition} | grep -Po '\d+')
        local fs=$(parted -mls | grep "^${part_no}" | cut -d: -f5)
        partitions+="${partition} raw ${label} ${fs};yes;${mount_point};target;no_opts;${label};no_params\n"
    done

    # do the swap
    if [ -e /dev/disk/by-label/swap ]
    then
        local partition=$(readlink -f /dev/disk/by-label/swap)
        partitions+="$partition raw swap swap;yes;no_mountpoint;target;no_opts;swap;no_params"
    else
        # if there's no labeled swap, use the first one we find
        local partition=$(fdisk -l | grep -m1 swap | awk '{ print $1 }')
        if [ ! -e $partition ]
        then
            echo "No swap detected. Giving up."
            exit 1
        fi
        partitions+="$partition raw no_label swap;yes;no_mountpoint;target;no_opts;no_label;no_params"
    fi

    echo -n ${partitions}
}
```

This worked fine on my machine with only one hard drive, but it failed (obviously) when running in my VM running on a LiveCD (the LiveCD was being picked up as another drive, /dev/sr0).

I've thought of a couple of hacks I could try:

- `mount $partition; grep $partition /etc/mtab | awk ...`
- use `parted -mls`, but pull out the partition I care about with clever scripting, then parse as I already do in the scriptt

Is there a better, simpler way of doing this? I already have the partitions I'm interested in, and I only need to find their filesystems (as well as find available swap).

Comment: @Mikel No, that question looks at a mounted filesystem. While you can mount the filesystem then see what type it's mounted as, this is slow, not robust, doesn't work for swap, only works for filesystems supported by the running kernel...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I found the answer: `blkid`

From the man page:

> The  blkid  program  is  the command-line interface to working with the
>   libblkid(3) library.  It  can  determine  the  type  of  content  (e.g.
>   filesystem  or  swap)  that  a  block device holds, and also attributes
>   (tokens, NAME=value pairs) from the content  metadata  (e.g.  LABEL  or
>   UUID fields).

Apparently it prints the device name along with the filesystem type (along with some other useful information). To get a list of all devices with their types:

```
blkid | sed 's!\(.*\):.*TYPE="\(.*\)".*!\1: \2!'
```

To find all `/dev/sd*/` devices, just add in a grep:

```
blkid | grep "/dev/sd.*" | sed 's!\(.*\):.*TYPE="\(.*\)".*!\1: \2!'
```

Then just `cut` or `awk` to get what you need.

Comment: blkid can filter what you need on its own - no need for sed/grep/awk magic: `blkid -s TYPE -o value /dev/sda3`

Comment: @PetrUzel - Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Remember to run with `sudo` if you are not root! This one caught me out because `blkid` does not print any error messages and exits with status code 0 if it cannot access block devices...

Comment: There's rarely a need to pipe `grep` to `sed`.  `grep foo | sed 's/pattern/repl/'` is more cleanly written `sed '/foo/s/pattern/repl/'`

Answer (score 9):

`file -s /path/to/device` will identify the filesystem on a disk/partition/slice.

A la:

```
[root@node2 ~]# file -s /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data (needs journa recovery) (large files)
[root@node2 ~]# file -s /dev/mapper/coraid--pool-coraid--lv1 
/dev/mapper/coraid--pool-coraid--lv1: Linux GFS2 Filesystem (blocksize 4096, lockproto lock_dlm)
[root@node2 ~]# file -s /dev/mapper/coraid--pool-coraid--lv2 
/dev/mapper/coraid--pool-coraid--lv2: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 256, v2 dirs)
```

at least, on Linux it does.

Comment: Is there a way to reliably filter out the filesystem type from a script?

Comment: depends on whether you consider the full name of the filesystem filtered enough, as in `| cut -d: -f2 | cut -d( -f1` or something.  It's not as pretty as `blkid`, that's for sure. :)

Answer (score 8):

Show only the block device's TYPE tag, and only output its value:

```
blkid -s TYPE -o value "$device"
```

Example:

```
$ blkid -s TYPE -o value /dev/mapper/vg_svelte-home 
btrfs
```

Answer (score 1):

A secondary option that works with many filesystems and has the benefit of working even with filesystems that have damaged structures is `testdisk`. (You can run `sudo apt install testdisk` to install it on Debian-based systems.)

Script it to return just the filesystem type like this:

```
$ testdisk /list "$path_to_partition" | awk '$1 == "P" {print $2}'
```