# How to show the filesystem type via the terminal?

Tags: linux, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell what type of filesystem you’re on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/how-to-tell-what-type-of-filesystem-youre-on)
>   [Find filesystem of an unmounted partition from a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43237/find-filesystem-of-an-unmounted-partition-from-a-script)

How can I quickly check the filesystem of the partition? Can I do that by using `df`?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Yes, according to man `df` you can:

> ```
> -T, --print-type      print file system type
> ```

Another way is to use the `mount` command. Without parameters it lists the currently mounted devices, including their file systems.

In case you need to find out only one certain file system, is easier to use the `stat` command's `-f` option instead of parsing out one value from the above mentioned commands' output.

Comment: `mount` won't show the file system mounted by fuse, just that it's a `fuseblk`

Comment: `stat -f /var`, for example.

Comment: @EvanCarroll in the `fuse` case, this helps: `lsblk -no name,fstype`

Comment: What's an example of a full `df` command to accomplish this? It seems to require more arguments than simply `-t` (mine does `-t` instead of `-T`).

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx, mine is the GNU coreutils `df` and for `-T` (list types) expects nothing else. For `-t` (filter types) indeed expects one of the files system types listed by `-T`. Sure when executing `df` on your machine is run the command you are expecting and not an alias or a function? The `type df` command may shed light on that. To make sure no alias or function with the same name interferes, try to execute `command df -T` instead. Here you can see how it works on my machine: https://pastebin.com/UkmNyNGG

Comment: @manatwork I'm using the df on Termux (on Android). When I do `df --version` it says `toybox 0.8.0-android`. There's no `-T` option on mine, but I do get similar output as your `-T` if I just run `df` with no arguments, except there's no type column.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx, unfortunately that implementation will not do it. Your best option may be `mount` without parameters, though that will probably display a huge list of mountpoints.

Answer (score 87):

If the filesystem is not mounted (but if it is as well):

```
blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/xxx
```

or:

```
file -Ls /dev/xxx
```

where `xxx` stands for actual block device name like `sda1`.

You'll generally need read access to the block device. However, in the case of `blkid`, if it can't read the device, it will try to get that information as cached in `/run/blkid/blkid.tab` or `/etc/blkid.tab`.

```
lsblk -no FSTYPE /dev/xxx
```

will also give you that information, this time by querying the `udev` data (something like `/run/udev/data/b$major:$minor`).

Comment: Perfect, this works also for unmounted filesystems and even images. And looks less weird than `(eval $(blkid $DEV | awk ' { print $3 } '); echo $TYPE)`...

Comment: I like this because it does not require mounting the device, and uses common "off the shelf" utilities, like `file` . Good stuff.

Comment: For exfat and probably other fuse mounted filesystems, only the last lsblk example works. Or `lsblk -f /dev/sdX` for more verbose output.

Comment: the most awesome answer in the internet ever