# How to determine the filesystem of an unmounted device?

Tags: filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find filesystem of a partition from a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43237/find-filesystem-of-a-partition-from-a-script)
>   [How to show the filesystem type via the terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53313/how-to-show-the-filesystem-type-via-the-terminal)

I'm looking for a command that yields the filesystem type as `mount` would use/detect it, without actually mounting it. It should also work e.g. for LUKS encrypted devices (where `file -s` yields "LUKS encrypted file" instead of "crypto_LUKS"). Surely there is a more convenient way than parsing `fsck -N /dev/whatever`'s output (which may use stderr depending on the existence of a corresponding `fsck.TYPE`)?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas that's not a duplicate, `df` reads mount table and doesn't show about unmounted ones.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get this information. Most of them require you to parse the output of another command.

- Run `# fdisk /dev/sdX -l` to get a basic idea of the filesystem structure. The output is something like this:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x9f7685a8

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1              63      289169      144553+  83  Linux
  /dev/sda2          289170   459121634   229416232+  83  Linux
  /dev/sda3       459121635   461129759     1004062+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
  /dev/sda4   *   461129760   625142447    82006344    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ```

  But this will only tell you the partition type.
- You could also use `# blkid` to get the following output:

  ```
  /dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="aa84c5a8-6408-4952-b577-578f2a67af86" TYPE="ext2" 
  /dev/sda2: LABEL="root" UUID="a430e0ef-fd35-432f-8b9a-75a49b89ad8a" TYPE="ext4" 
  /dev/sda3: LABEL="swap" UUID="e388806a-dc27-4f4e-a136-3d1ff4e53962" TYPE="swap" 
  /dev/sda4: UUID="088E027A8E026114" TYPE="ntfs"
  ```
- Also, for a well formatted output, you could run `# parted /dev/sdX -l` for the following output:

  ```
  Model: ATA WDC WD3200BEVT-7 (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: msdos
  Disk Flags: 

  Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
   1      32.3kB  148MB  148MB   primary  ext2
   2      148MB   235GB  235GB   primary  ext4
   3      235GB   236GB  1028MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
   4      236GB   320GB  84.0GB  primary  ntfs            boot
  ```
- `$ df -T`. This is another command that does not require super user privileges to execute. However, this will report for every mount point

  ```
  Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
  rootfs         rootfs   225815276 99381340 114963128  47% /
  dev            devtmpfs   1538396        0   1538396   0% /dev
  run            tmpfs      1541260      416   1540844   1% /run
  /dev/sda2      ext4     225815276 99381340 114963128  47% /
  tmpfs          tmpfs      1541260      360   1540900   1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs          tmpfs      1541260        0   1541260   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs          tmpfs      1541260      900   1540360   1% /tmp
  /dev/sda1      ext2        139985    30386    102372  23% /boot
  /dev/sda4      fuseblk   82006340 79676036   2330304  98% /mnt
  ```

Another command that can come handy is `# file -sL /dev/sdXY`. This has one downside in that it does not work with the full block device. Requires the exact device to be passed. The output is quite neat though:

```
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=aa84c5a8-6408-4952-b577-578f2a67af86, volume name "boot"
```

All of these will always be output to stdout. You can parse them in a script if required.

Comment: `(eval $(blkid $DEV  | awk ' { print $3 } '); echo $TYPE)` will do, thanks! (The outer parantheses are only necessary if `TYPE` is already used elsewhere and shall not be changed)

Comment: `df -T` will claim `tmpfs` for any loopdevice it seems, and `fdisk -l` doesn't appear to list a type when applied to a partition itself, while `parted` ignores the device for me and `file -s` yields the wrong format for a luks encrypted device. But `blkid` works perfectly, even for a loop device or the image file itself

Comment: That behavior is expected out of `df -T` and `fdisk -l`. However, I don't understand how `parted` ignores the complete block device.

Comment: That may be due to the linux I tried to run this on (it's a custom distro on a Buffalo LinkStation NAS device) Btw, even better solution: [`blkid -o value -s TYPE $DEV`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53371/863)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Instead of eval, you could use `. <(blkid -pi /dev/sdXN)`

Comment: @F.Hauri Good point, I didn't know about `<(...)` back then though. And of course the `blkid -i value -s TYPE $DEV` is even better...

Comment: `#lsblk -f` would also help at least it returns every mounted or unmount block devices.

Comment: None of these work with NFS mountpoints.

Comment: All those commands also work if the FS is mounted.

Comment: At times, lsblk takes a while to update itself. "blkid -p /dev/mapper/mpathb -s TYPE -o value" would force it to probe low-level superblocks bypassing cache.