# lsblk alternative for busybox?

Tags: busybox

I installed busybox on my Android device.
The command list is very long but lsblk is no supported as this log shows:

```
...
Currently defined functions:
    [, [[, acpid, adjtimex, ar, arp, ash, awk, base64, basename, bbconfig, beep, blkdiscard, blkid, blockdev, bootchartd, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, bzip2, cal, cat, catv, chat, chattr, chgrp, chmod, chown, chpst, chroot, chrt, chvt, cksum, clear, cmp, comm,
    conspy, cp, cpio, crond, crontab, cryptpw, cttyhack, cut, date, dc, dd, deallocvt, devfsd, devmem, df, diff, dirname, dmesg, dnsd, dnsdomainname, dos2unix, dpkg, dpkg-deb, du, dumpkmap, echo, ed, egrep, env, envdir, envuidgid, ether-wake, expand, expr,
    fakeidentd, false, fatattr, fbset, fbsplash, fdflush, fdformat, fdisk, fgconsole, fgrep, find, findfs, flock, fold, free, freeramdisk, fsck, fsck.minix, fstrim, fsync, ftpd, ftpget, ftpput, fuser, getopt, grep, groups, gunzip, gzip, halt, hd, hdparm, head,
    hexdump, hostname, httpd, hush, hwclock, i2cdetect, i2cdump, i2cget, i2cset, id, ifconfig, ifdown, ifenslave, ifplugd, ifup, inetd, init, inotifyd, install, ionice, iostat, ip, ipaddr, ipcalc, iplink, ipneigh, iproute, iprule, iptunnel, kbd_mode, kill,
    killall, killall5, klogd, less, linux32, linux64, linuxrc, ln, loadkmap, logger, logname, losetup, lpd, lpq, lpr, ls, lsattr, lsof, lspci, lsusb, lzcat, lzma, lzop, lzopcat, makedevs, makemime, man, md5sum, mesg, mkdir, mkdosfs, mke2fs, mkfifo, mkfs.ext2,
    mkfs.minix, mkfs.reiser, mkfs.vfat, mknod, mkpasswd, mkswap, mktemp, modinfo, more, mount, mountpoint, mpstat, mt, mv, nameif, nbd-client, nc, netstat, nice, nmeter, nohup, nsenter, nslookup, ntpd, od, openvt, patch, pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6,
    pipe_progress, pivot_root, pkill, pmap, popmaildir, poweroff, powertop, printenv, printf, ps, pscan, pstree, pwd, pwdx, raidautorun, rdate, rdev, readlink, readprofile, realpath, reboot, reformime, renice, reset, resize, rev, rfkill, rm, rmdir, route, rpm,
    rpm2cpio, rtcwake, run-parts, runsv, runsvdir, rx, script, scriptreplay, sed, sendmail, seq, setarch, setconsole, setkeycodes, setlogcons, setserial, setsid, setuidgid, sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha3sum, sha512sum, showkey, shuf, slattach, sleep, smemcap,
    softlimit, sort, split, start-stop-daemon, stat, strings, stty, sum, sv, svc, svlogd, swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl, tac, tail, tar, taskset, tcpsvd, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, tftp, tftpd, time, timeout, top, touch, tr, traceroute,
    traceroute6, true, truncate, tty, ttysize, tunctl, tune2fs, ubiattach, ubidetach, ubimkvol, ubirmvol, ubirsvol, ubiupdatevol, udpsvd, uevent, umount, uname, uncompress, unexpand, uniq, unix2dos, unlink, unlzma, unlzop, unshare, unxz, unzip, uptime, usleep,
    uudecode, uuencode, vconfig, vi, volname, watch, watchdog, wc, wget, which, whoami, whois, xargs, xz, xzcat, yes, zcat, zcip
gts210vewifi:/data/local/tmp $ ./busybox lsblk                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
lsblk: applet not found
```

Is there an alternative command supported by busybox which can show all disks and partitions?

Comment: Does `ls /sys/block` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stat disk drives wihout lsblk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127186/stat-disk-drives-wihout-lsblk)