# Problem copying a directory larger than 6 GB

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

I have a problem when I want copy a directory to a disk external, but the directory has size 6 GB.

When try copy it, it gives me a error: " File too large",

I give more information, that directory has a format  ext4, my disk external has format NTFS.

Not should I have had  this problem, because such as ext4 as NTFS allows this function (when I say "allows this Function" I'm saying that allows copy files larger than 4 GB)

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
Ram 16 GB

---

```
elisur@elisur:~/Movies$ cp -rv Metallica\ Through\ The\ Never/ /media/elisur/SP\ PHD\ U3/Movies\ Backup/
'Metallica Through The Never/Metallica.ThroughTheNever2013.720pVATAKy.mkv' -> '/media/elisur/SP PHD U3/Movies Backup/Metallica Through The Never/Metallica.ThroughTheNever2013.720pVATAKy.mkv'
cp: error writing '/media/elisur/SP PHD U3/Movies Backup/Metallica Through The Never/Metallica.ThroughTheNever2013.720pVATAKy.mkv': File too large
```

Comment: First, I assume you mean `NTFS` not `NFS` right?  Second, when you are copying the directory, how are you doing it?

Comment: Sorry, you are right is NTFS. This is me process: cp -r /directory /media/user/disk external. thank for your help.

Comment: @elisur, Did you check the file the copy stops on, if it's larger than 4 GB? (`cp -v` would show the list of files while copying, if it doesn't otherwise show the file name). Also, you can [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/350310/edit) your question to fix those typos..

Comment: If the name of your disk really is "disk external", you should put the path in quotes or escape the space between `disk`and `external`. And run `cp -ir`to see what's happening.

Comment: @ridgy that wouldn't explain the error message. And the `-i` won't help, it only does anything when the target already exists and will be overwritten.

Comment: You can use rsync command to do it when you had a problem with cp command.

Comment: @elisur please [edit] your question and show us i) the *exact* command you used and ii) the *exact* error message received. 6GB is not particularly large and there is no limit to the size of files in a directory. There is only a limit to the maximum size of a single file but in NTFS that is 256 terabytes so, again, that can't be the issue.

Comment: My best guess is that you've mididentified the file system. It's likely a variant of FAT and not NTFS. Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53313/how-to-show-the-filesystem-type-via-the-terminal

Comment: What's the output of `mount | grep /dev/sd`?  Please [edit] this (and your previous comment) into the question itself

Comment: why do have I  that edit my question if still I haven't Solved my problem? @terdon

Comment: @elisur because that way someone might be able to solve your problem. If you don't edit, your question is incomplete so nobody will be able to help you. You have been asked for various pieces of information: all of that needs to be in your question so that we can understand what the problem is. So please [edit] and add the answers to the comments.