# Identifiy file system for the device /dev/sdc1

Tags: filesystems, rhel

I started an old Virtual Machine in the UAT environment. 
The output for `uname -a` is :

```
Linux pawana 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There 3 disks attached to it.

1) `/dev/sda` => contains the OS partitions and LV's

2) `/dev/sdb1` => is an ext2 file system

3) `/dev/sdc[1-3]` => could not mount these device using the mount command.

so I used the command `file -sL /dev/sdc[1-3]` to identify the file system type for the device. Below is the output :

```
[root@pawana ~]# file -sL /dev/sdc[1-3]

/dev/sdc1: data

/dev/sdc2: data

/dev/sdc3: data
```

What type of file system is this ?? If at all it contains any data how can access that ?

Comment: Are any of the `/dev/sdc[123]` partitions mentioned in `/etc/fstab`?  Or anywhere in `/etc` (`grep -irl 'sdc[123]' /etc`)?  Does the VM have any apps installed that make use of raw, unformatted partitions?  (e.g. the oracle database software can optionally use raw partitions).  BTW, if `file -s` can't identify the partition type(s), it's probably not a formatted filesystem.  Maybe try hexdumping it, e.g.  `hd /dev/sdc1 | less` and see if there's anything you recognise.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43237/find-filesystem-of-an-unmounted-partition-from-a-script?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
fsck -N /dev/sdc1
```

If that doesn't work you can try with the mount `auto` option to see if it gets mounted but looking at your file output it could be just no filesystem on it.

Comment: `mount` was already tried. It's possible, but unlikely, that `fsck` would recognize a filesystem that the kernel (invoked through mount) wouldn't recognize.