# Why this switch will effectively format disk to ext2 instead of ext4?

Tags: ext4, ext2

I'm formatting a disk with following command switches, I can format the disk to ext4.

```
sudo mke2fs -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard -t ext4 -b 4096 ...
```

However, once I added this switch:

```
-O ^has_journal
```

It will be formatted to ext2. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ext4 is an extension of the ext2 and ext3 filesystems; one of the features that it extended was the use of a journal.

References:

- https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#What_is_the_difference_between_ext2.2C_ext3.2C_and_ext4.3F
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60757/117549

Comment: So, you are saying, by disabling the journal feature, I'm installing a subset of ext4, that is why it is only shown as ext2? What I really want to know is, does this volume have all other advantages from ext4. Thanks!

Comment: I can't speak to the details of ext4, but I suspect that is why it's displaying as ext2 -- without a journal, it can't be called ext4. See also [man mkfs.ext4](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) where it says: and "mke2fs -t ext3 -O ^has_journal /dev/hdXX" will create a filesystem that does not have a journal and hence will not be supported by the ext3 filesystem code in the Linux kernel.)"