# How to detect NTFS/exFAT file system type from script

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, ntfs, exfat

User has a (incremental) backup script using `rsync`, to external device.  This was erroring on an SSD he had.  Turns out his device was formatted `exFAT`.  That means I need to detect this *in the script*, as I need to alter the options to `rsync` (e.g., exFAT cannot handle symbolic links, no owner/group permissions, etc.).

User is running Linux Mint.  I run Ubuntu.  I can only assume/hope that a solution for my Ubuntu will work for his Mint.

I have looked at:

- [How do I know if a partition is ext2, ext3, or ext4?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/how-do-i-know-if-a-partition-is-ext2-ext3-or-ext4)
- [How to tell what type of filesystem you're on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/how-to-tell-what-type-of-filesystem-youre-on)
- https://www.tecmint.com/find-linux-filesystem-type/

There are a variety of good suggestions there, but I do not see one which meets my requirements, which are:

- Must report (parseable) `ntfs`/`exfat` explicitly, not just say `fuseblk` (which it will for both `exfat` & `ntfs`, I need to distinguish).
- Must *not* require **sudo**.
- Must be executable starting from a directory path on the file system (can assume it will be mounted), not just starting from a `/dev/...`.

From the suggestions I have tried:

- `fdisk -l`, `parted -l`, `file -sL`: require **sudo** and/or `/dev/...` block device
- `mount`: requires `/dev/...`, only reports `fuseblk`
- `df -T`, `stat -f -c %T`: accept directory, but report only `fuseblk`
- `lsblk -f`, `blkid`: require `/dev/...` block device

Is there a single, simple command which meets all these criteria?  Or, `lsblk`/`blkid` seem to report `exfat`/`ntfs` correctly, if I need to pass them the `/dev` how do I get that suitably from the directory path in script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to the other posters for replying/suggesting.  Here is my full solution.

`df -P` can be used to obtain device from path, and that can be fed to `lsblk --fs` to obtain exact file system.  So a one-liner is:

```
fs=$( lsblk --fs --noheadings $( df -P $path | awk 'END{print $1}' ) | awk 'END{print $2}' )
```

If all you need to know is that the file system is `fuseblk` --- which covers both `ntfs` & `exfat` and turns out in the end to be sufficient for my purposes after all --- this can be determined with the much simpler:

```
fs=$( stat -f -c '%T' $path )
```

Comment: Interesting problem... good to hear you got this worked out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I follow your question completely, so I'll offer this as a "point of departure". If it gets you close, I'm sure you can tweak it to get what you need:

```
$ lsblk --fs | grep / | awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

what about `df .` and `mount` ?

first let's get mount point

```
 cd /a/dir
 mp=$(df . | awk 'NR==2 { print $1}')
```

- `$mp` while hold device name hoding `/a/dir`

now, mount point

```
mount | awk -v mp=$mp '$1 == mp { print $5}'
```

this should return mount type (be it `xfs`, `etx3`, ...)

edit:

- I see my answer is covered in one of the link, you might whish to explore line returned by mount, not just `$5`

Comment: As I said, `mount` reports `type fuseblk`, which is why I didn't discover `ntfs`/`exfat` in the first place?  But if your `df` command is how to convert directory to `/dev` maybe I can use it with `blkid`/`lsblk -f` which do seem to report exact fs.

Comment: I don't have a ubuntu with ntfs/fat at hand, I'll give a look later on.