# `stat -f` show a ext4 file system type as ext2/ext3

Tags: linux, filesystems, stat

On Ubuntu 14.04, I am checking the ext4 filesystem for my home based on a file `new` in it:

```
$ stat -f new
  File: "new"
    ID: 38d4cd29e44142c6 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 144152970  Free: 79424314   Available: 72095994
Inodes: Total: 36626432   Free: 35430143
```

why does `stat -f` show the file system type is ext2/ext3 while my home filesystem type is ext4?

Comment: Have you ever seen `stat` output `ext4`? Probably is just doesn't care.

Comment: I have seldom used `stat`, and I haven't seen `stat` output `ext4`.

Comment: you'[re](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/how-to-tell-what-type-of-filesystem-youre-on#comment444069_34636) right I recommend `df -T` instead.

Comment: Use `blkid` - it will hunt through the superblock looking at various flags to determine whether the filesystem is ext2, ext3, or ext4.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking `stat -f` doesn't differentiate between ext2, ext3 and ext4. Instead, it just shows them as ext2/ext3 and [probably](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2013-01/msg00172.html) ext2/ext3/ext4.

So, it is not good ideat to use `stat -f` to check specific `ext` type file-system. You can use `df -T` from coreutils for such purpose.

From manpage:

```
NAME
       df - report file system disk space usage
```

```
       -T, --print-type
              print file system type
```