# How do I find out which partitions my filesystems (and mount points) are on, and how full the partitions are?

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk-usage

This question is essentially the *opposite* of the first question below, and adjacently related to the second question, and is therefore not a duplicate:

1. [Ask Ubuntu: How do I find out what filesystem my partitions are using?](https://askubuntu.com/q/309047/327339)
2. [Unix & Linux: How to tell what type of filesystem you're on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34623/114401)

`df -h` shows my filesystems. Ex:

```bash
$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      1.6G  2.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  467G  410G   33G  93% /
tmpfs                      7.8G  139M  7.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                 9.0M  9.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/146
/dev/loop1                 128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2                 165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop3                  82M   82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop9                 291M  291M     0 100% /snap/vault/2012
/dev/loop10                 46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/638
/dev/loop7                 347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/sda2                  704M  305M  348M  47% /boot
/dev/loop6                  43M   43M     0 100% /snap/leafpad/91
/dev/loop8                 321M  321M     0 100% /snap/vlc/3078
/dev/loop11                 46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/599
/dev/loop16                219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop13                117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14399
/dev/loop15                296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/sda1                  511M   26M  486M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/loop14                 64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1738
/dev/loop12                 92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop17                219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop19                256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
/dev/loop21                9.0M  9.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/164
/dev/loop18                 50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17883
/dev/loop23                347M  347M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop20                163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
tmpfs                      1.6G  196K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop24                 56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2667
/dev/loop25                 64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1778
/dev/loop4                 117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14447
/dev/loop5                  50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17950
/dev/loop26                 56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2679
```

I want to know which partition each filesystem is on, in particular my root filesystem mounted at `/`. I'd also like to know how full each partition is.

How can I find this out? Using GUI tools to prove that your command-line tools worked is ok, but ultimately I need command-line tools as I need to run this on minimalistic remote embedded Linux edge devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out at least one way. Other answers are welcome.

##### Summary

My `/` root mount point is on the `/dev/sda3` partition (as seen at the bottom of `lsblk`).

And, my `/dev/sda3` partition is about *(410 GiB (used in `vgubuntu-root`, as shown by `df -h`) + 0.980 GiB (used in `vgubuntu-swap`, as shown by `lsblk`))/(475.7 GiB (total in `sda3`, as shown by `lsblk`)) = 410.98/475.7 = **86.4% full.***

Key partition or filesystem-related commands:

```bash
# get disk usage and see mount points (but not partitions :()
df -h

# see which partition your filesystems are on, and how big they are
lsblk

# and on embedded Linux devices with BusyBox:
mountpoint -n /

# ---------------------

# and maybe useful
blkid

# see also
sudo fdisk -l

# get additional partition info for `/dev/sda3`
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda3
```

### Details

The end of `lsblk` shows all of my partitions, their size, and which mount point they are mounted to. On my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, notice the part beginning with `sda` near the end. That's where my physical partitions start:

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                   7:0    0     9M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/146
loop1                   7:1    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2                   7:2    0 164.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop3                   7:3    0  81.3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop4                   7:4    0 116.7M  1 loop  /snap/core/14447
loop5                   7:5    0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/17950
loop6                   7:6    0  42.7M  1 loop  /snap/leafpad/91
loop7                   7:7    0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop8                   7:8    0 320.4M  1 loop  /snap/vlc/3078
loop9                   7:9    0 290.1M  1 loop  /snap/vault/2012
loop10                  7:10   0    46M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/638
loop11                  7:11   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/599
loop12                  7:12   0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop13                  7:13   0 116.7M  1 loop  /snap/core/14399
loop14                  7:14   0  63.2M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1738
loop15                  7:15   0 295.7M  1 loop  /snap/vlc/2344
loop16                  7:16   0   219M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop17                  7:17   0   219M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop18                  7:18   0  49.6M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/17883
loop19                  7:19   0   140K  1 loop  /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop20                  7:20   0 162.9M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop21                  7:21   0     9M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/164
loop23                  7:23   0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop24                  7:24   0  55.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2667
loop25                  7:25   0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1778
loop26                  7:26   0  55.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2679
sda                     8:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 475.7G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt        253:0    0 475.7G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 474.8G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

So, the root mount point (`/`) is on `vgubuntu-root` within partition `sda3`. Its full partition hierarchy is `sda/sda3/sda3_crypt/vgubuntu-root`. The `gparted` GUI confirms this and shows it like this:

[image]

On embedded Linux boards running BusyBox (Ubuntu doesn't have the `-n` option, for instance), you can also use `mountpoint -n <mount_point>`. Ex: `mountpoint -n /` would show something like this, confirming that the `/` filesystem mount point is on partition `/dev/sda3`:

```bash
$ mountpoint -n /
/dev/sda3 /
```

Again, on Ubuntu, the `-n` option doesn't exist, but on a board with BusyBox, the help menu when you run just `mountpoint` says:

```bash
# mountpoint
BusyBox v1.31.1 (2023-01-26 07:37:10 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: mountpoint [-q] <[-dn] DIR | -x DEVICE>

Check if the directory is a mountpoint

    -q  Quiet
    -d  Print major/minor device number of the filesystem
    -n  Print device name of the filesystem
    -x  Print major/minor device number of the blockdevice
```

So, `-n` will `Print device name of the filesystem`.

Now that we know from `lsblk` or `mountpoint -n /` that the partition for this filesystem (and root mountpoint) is `/dev/sda3`, we can get more partition info with:

```bash
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda3
```

Example run and output:

```bash
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda3
[sudo] password for gabriel: 
Disk /dev/sda3: 475.74 GiB, 510804361216 bytes, 997664768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

The size is 475.74 GiB, as also previously shown by `lsblk`.

Previously from `lsblk`:

```
└─sda3                  8:3    0 475.7G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt        253:0    0 475.7G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 474.8G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

So we can see my root filesystem mounted at `/` is only allotted 474.8 GiB of the 475.7 GiB total in partition `/dev/sda3`.

`df -h` from my question previously showed:

```bash
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  467G  410G   33G  93% /
```

So, my `/dev/sda3` partition is about *(410 GiB (used in `vgubuntu-root`, as shown by `df -h`) + 0.980 GiB (used in `vgubuntu-swap`, as shown by `lsblk`))/(475.7 GiB (total in `sda3`, as shown by `lsblk`)) = 410.98/475.7 = **86.4% full.***

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` to show only the filesystems you're interested in.  e.g.

```
$ df -h | grep ^/dev/ | grep -vE '^/dev/(loop|shm)'
```

Better yet, use `awk` (because piping grep into grep is kind of silly, and because awk can use boolean operators - e.g. AND `&&`,  OR `||`, and NOT `!` -  in patterns):

```
df -h | awk 'NR==1; /^\/dev\// && ! /^\/dev\/(loop|shm)/'
```

This prints the first line (the header) and any line starting with `/dev/` except for those with /dev/shm or /dev/loop.  On your system, with the sample `df -h` output you posted, it would show:

```
$ awk 'NR==1; /^\/dev/ && ! /dev\/(loop|shm)/' /tmp/df-sample.txt
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  467G  410G   33G  93% /
/dev/sda2                  704M  305M  348M  47% /boot
/dev/sda1                  511M   26M  486M   6% /boot/efi
```

Adjust the regular expressions to suit your needs.

---

NOTE: this won't work with any ZFS filesystems - they're mounted as pool/dataset, not from /dev.  e.g. on my system with the rootfs and several other filesystems on pool "hex", as well as an mdadm raid1 ext4 for /boot and a FAT partition for /boot/efi (all of these are partitions on the same pair of identical NVME drives - contrary to what a lot of people think, ZFS works perfectly well with partitions, you don't have to give it entire disks):

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem                 Type  Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
hex/ROOT                   zfs   243G  14G   229G   6%    /
/dev/md0                   ext4  2.0G  335M  1.5G   18%   /boot
/dev/nvme1n1p2             vfat  511M  49M   463M   10%   /boot/efi
hex/local                  zfs   230G  855M  229G   1%    /usr/local
hex/home                   zfs   257G  28G   229G   11%   /home
hex/var                    zfs   229G  128K  229G   1%    /var
...
...
```

But,since you know the pool name, you can adjust the regex to suit, e.g.:

```
df -h | awk 'NR==1; /^(\/dev|hex)/ && ! /dev\/(loop|shm)/'
```

or matching of the fs type (`df -T`):

```
df -Th | awk 'NR==1 || $2 ~ /zfs|btrfs|ext|fat|xfs/'
```

See also GNU df's `-t` option to limit what kind of filesystems will be displayed, and the `-x` option for excluding fs types.

Answer (score 0):

I like this command - lsblk

```
fred@Z170-jammy:~$ lsblk -e 7 -o model,name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid
MODEL NAME     FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL  PARTLABEL          MOUNTPOINT UUID
HGST  sda             931.5G                                             
      ├─sda1   vfat   510.2M        ESP_B  EFI System Partition
      │                                                                  F496-1330
      ├─sda2   ext4    30.3G   6.1G hirsute
      │                                    hirsute            /media/fre 2888d7ab-23e4-4981-8566-7e23335be781
      ├─sda3   ext4    49.8G    40K ISO_b  ISO_b              /media/fre c395f36d-5e02-4913-a904-e336054b2eff
      ├─sda4   ext4   147.6G 115.6G backup_b
      │                                    backup_b           /media/fre dd4e4a2e-4785-4441-91b0-28234b98e625
      ├─sda5   ext4    30.3G   6.2G focal_a
      │                                    focal_a            /media/fre f2cde08c-a045-43ef-83bd-a4132aa23fbd
      ├─sda6   ext4   302.7G 117.8G data   data               /media/fre f9537995-8b44-4abb-b5fb-ec27023f57b2
      ├─sda7   swap     2.1G                                             3ef43e7c-8a35-4f8b-bc73-c91d6098d4cd
      ├─sda8   ext4    24.4G   8.2G impish impish             /media/fre a269adca-248f-4633-a06d-01348ae42d3a
      ├─sda9   ext4      24G   6.9G groovy_k
      │                                    groovy_k           /media/fre 6fadac33-0cdc-4005-940c-a4d035058dd8
      └─sda10  ext4    33.3G   9.7G jammy-b
                                           jammy_b            /media/fre aa644837-3a50-4cc3-b5b9-683172ea7d60
Samsu nvme0n1         465.8G                                             
      ├─nvme0n1p1
      │        vfat     512M  16.2M ESP_NVME
      │                                    esp_nvme           /boot/efi  4954-C122
      ├─nvme0n1p2
      │        ext4    29.3G   8.7G focal_0
      │                                    focal_0            /media/fre b913e1bc-6f08-4984-b653-9a604d95470a
      ├─nvme0n1p3
      │        ext4    29.3G  10.1G focal_k
      │                                    focal_k            /media/fre 54029c4f-0cbe-413e-80ce-78a4995b0551
      ├─nvme0n1p4
      │        ext4    29.3G  15.7G jammy  jammy              /          9da6b198-e2ca-4e27-8a18-6daf4ecfc324
      └─nvme0n1p5
               ext4   195.3G 134.9G nvme_data
                                           nvme_data          /mnt/data  1a44f4af-6780-4bbd-ad0b-6385ed30830b
```